How to write values to multiple rows in excel when using "write to excel worksheet"
I am reading from two excel worksheets in my flow, and writing the data from those into a third new one (merging the data).
The issue is that the merged data is only writing onto row 1
The problem is because the "Write to Excel worksheet" action I have is set to write the data there and I know that is wrong...
But I can't see how to write the data onto rows using the other "write mode" options (e.g. on currently active cell, on named cells), so that each value has its own cell in rows in column A.
Do I need to initiate a variate and set a counter to do this, or can this be done within the write action?
Screenshots attached below for reference!
Thanks for any help
Flow Image

Write to Excel action

Output of running the action (the mistake)

How I want the data to be written by the action
{]4
